# How can I show two alphabets in my contact list?

Tags: contacts, languages

I have a Galaxy S with an interface in Hebrew. Some of my contacts are in English and some are in Hebrew. However, I only have the option to scroll through the letters in Hebrew. The English alphabet is simply not there.

Is there any way to show the English alphabet as well so that I can scroll through the English letters too?

Comment: Are the contacts beginning with Arabic characters (English Alphabet) all grouped together or something, or are they not shown at all?

Comment: not a fix, but might help, if you press the search button, you can type the contact's name.

Comment: @Matthew: they're grouped together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with the default Contacts app (and I don't know of any third-party ones).  Android's language/locale support is very basic -- for example, your date format cannot be changed independently unlike, say, Windows -- so I recommend filing a bug with Google, hopefully it will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it seems to do it when your display language is Hebrew, but not when it's English. Almost there.

Comment: You're saying that it wasn't working in 2011, but now (2014) it's partially working. Is that right?

Comment: yes. In 2011 it wasn't implemented. Today it implemented, but unfortunately not turned on. There Should be more configuration.