# FastScroll contacts with multiple languages

Tags: contacts, localization

Some of my contacts are in one language, some are in another. I want the Contacts app to show a fast scroll index on the right for both languages. Currently, it is only like that if the display language is Hebrew. Is there a way to do it also when the display language is English?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/how-can-i-show-two-alphabets-in-my-contact-list?rq=1 asks the same question. Maybe 3 years of android development have gotten a more hopeful answer